# Understanding the sequential definition of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-writing

I am struggling to justify the sequential definition of derivative.

In my textbook's proof of the interior-extremum theorem:

> **Interior Extremum Theorem.** Let $f$ be differentiable on an open interval $(a,b)$. If $f$ attains a maximum value at some point $c\in(a,b)$, then $f'(c)=0$. The same is true if $f(c)$ is a minimum value.

The proof they give start with:

> **Proof.** Because $c$ is an open interval $(a,b)$, we can construct two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$, which converge to $c$ and satisfy $x_n<c<y_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The fact that $f(c)$ is a maximum implies that $f(y_n) −f(c)≤0$ for all n, and thus $f'(c)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(y_n)-f(c)}{y_n-c}... $

I have trouble understanding the last part. I get $f'(c)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(y_n)-f(c)}{y_n-c} $ intuitively because as $n\rightarrow \infty, 
 y_n\rightarrow c$ so this is equivalent to the standard definition 
 $f'(c)=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} $. But I still have trouble proving this formally, can somebody help?

Comment: Are you familiar with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit?

Comment: @ervx yes, it turned out that I was beating around the bush when i tried the proof :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Exercise.** Let $g:U\to\Bbb R$ be a function defined in some neighborhood $U$ of a point $c\in\Bbb R$, possibly excluding $c$ itself. Show that $\lim_{x\to c}g(x) = L$ if and only if for every sequence $x_n \to c$, we also have $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n) = L$.

*One direction.* If $g(x)\to L$, then let $\epsilon>0$ and $x_n\to c$. Since $g(x)\to L$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|g(x)-L|<\epsilon$. If $N$ is sufficiently large and $n>N$, then $|x_n-x|<\delta$. Thus for all $n$
sufficiently large we have $|g(x_n) - L| < \epsilon$, so that $g(x_n)\to L$ as $n\to\infty$, as desired.

Now apply this result to
$
g(x) = \dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}.
$

Answer (score 2):

$ f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ means that no matter how $x$ approaches $c$, the ratio $\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ will always tend to $f'(c)$. In particular, approaching $c$ via the points $y_{n}$ is one such way.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that clarified what I was confused on!

Comment: You are welcome.